# Constant-factor approximation algorithms for max-min number partitioning

Tags: reference-request, scheduling, approximation-algorithms

In the [k-way number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) problem, the input is a set of numbers and the goal is to partition them into $k$ parts in an optimal way. The most well-studied optimization objective is to *minimize* the *largest* sum; this problem is equivalent to minimizing the makespan when scheduling jobs on $k$ identical machines. For this objective, there are [practical constant-factor approximation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning#Minimizing_the_largest_sum), attaining 4/3 or 6/5 or 7/6 or 13/11 approximation.

I am interested in the dual objective - to *maximize* the *smallest* sum. For this objective, there is a PTAS - but it is considered impractical since the run-time is polynomial with a very high degree. [There is also a constant-factor approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning#Maximizing_the_smallest_sum), which attains an approximation factor of 3/4. *My question is:* are there practical algorithms that attain a better constant-factor approximation for the max-min objective? I am looking for something comparable to the min-max objective, e.g. 4/5 or 5/6 or 6/7 or 11/13.